# Does an object moving with uniform velocity require a force to maintain its motion?

Tags: forces

How does a trolley move with uniform velocity on a long board which has one of this ends raised to compensate for friction? If the trolley was given a gentle push down the long board, won't the trolley accelerate since a force was exerted on it? Because in my textbook it says " the trolley is given a gentle push down the board until it begins to move with uniform velocity." How does this happen pls explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your title question, if an object is moving with a constant velocity then the *net force* is $0$. However, this does not mean that there are no forces are acting on the object. For example (looking ahead to your example) if friction is present then a force is needed to counteract friction so that the net force is $0$ after the object is moving.

> If the trolley was given a gentle push down the long board, won't the trolley accelerate since a force was exerted on it? Because in my textbook it says " the trolley is given a gentle push down the board until it begins to move with uniform velocity."

The push is to get the trolley moving. Then the trolley starts moving at a constant velocity down the incline since the component of gravity parallel to the ramp exactly cancels the force due to friction. Of course going between at rest and moving there must be acceleration, which is provided by the push.

Comment: if the component of the trolley's weight exactly cancels out the frictional force then the sum of the forces on the trolley is zero, so if  the trolley is now pushed, a force is exerted on it and it will therefore accelerate, and if it accelerates its velocity will keep on changing and uniform motion can never be attained. So how is uniform motion attained in this case, pls clarify.

Comment: @Taofeek The initial push the book says is just to initially get the trolley moving. Then there is no more push. The push isn't present continuously as the trolley moves down the hill.

Comment: I had the misconception that once a force is applied on an object it continues accelerating to infinity

Comment: @Taofeek Oh ok. Yeah that's only true if the net force keeps being applied

Comment: @Taofeek If there is an answer that sufficiently answers your question, please consider marking it as the correct answer for future readers of this question.

Comment: what exactly is gravitational attraction? Does it differ from gravity? Is it the same as weight? Pls clarify thanks a lot.

Comment: @Taofeek If you have a new question, then please post a new question. The comments of an answer is not the place to ask new questions

Answer (score 2):

> Does an object moving with uniform velocity require a force to maintain its motion?

No.  By $\vec F=m\vec a$ if there is no change in velocity (i.e. the velocity is uniform) then $\vec a=0$ and thus the net force $\vec F=0$.

In practice, there is some rolling friction that will slow down the trolley unless some other force, like gravity, exactly compensates to make the net force is $0$, which is a *necessary* condition for uniform motion.